# syncfusion dashboard designer connect to custom oAuth datasource

Tags: dashboard, syncfusion, dashboard-designer

Is it possible to connect to custom OAuth data source in the dashboard designer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Syncfusion dashboard designer do not have support to connect custom OAuth data source with designer application. it can able to connect only listed providers which are showed in provider combo box of OAuth new connection window.

Please refer to the below link to know more about connecting through OAuth. 
https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-designer/connecting-via-oauth